# Flex gives error for every character in file

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm trying to get flex and bison working on my windows machine. I have installed flex, bison, and mingw compiler. i have a file named test.l in my flex bin folder that contains the following code:

```
%{
int chars = 0;
%}

%%
. { chars++; }
%%

main()
{
  yylex();
  printf("yay: %d", chars);
}
```

Flex is giving me nine bad character errors from line one, then a few "unknown error processing section 1" errors. Each line is about the same, give or take a few unknown character errors. Final error is premature EOF at the end of line 13.

Is this a sign that I have things installed incorrectly, or have I seriously messed up somewhere in this simple test file?

Comment: It sounds to me like an encoding issue. Does test.l actually start with a byte order mark? (Use hd to view the actual bytes in the file.)

Comment: Once you get this to compile, you will discover that the pattern `.` does not match a newline character. `%option nodefault` is useful to catch errors like that.